# Send parameters by url in post method and know the file

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I want to do a login into a web using the URL. The login form is in this web https://www.kindertic.com/en/log-in

and the source code is like this

```
    <form method="POST" name="form-login">
  <div><input type="text" maxlength="25" name="usernamekt" id="username"/></div>
  <div><input type="password" name="passwd" maxlength="30" id="passwd"/></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Log in" class="input-submit" name="enviar-login"/></div>
</form>
```

I have tried to do this https://www.kindertic.com/en/log-in?usernamekt=XXXXXX&passwd=YYYYYY but nothing happens. How can I do that?

Other thing is to know what is the file that opens the redirection or this webpage?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is https://www.kindertic.com/en/log-in?usernamekt=XXXXXX&passwd=YYYYYY then you need `<form method="GET">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but website is not mine and I only want to do a login. This url is not working for my pourpose. Finally I decided to show the website in an Android WebView and when the user makes login the WebView will disappear.